# not able to add data item to list view in titanium

Tags: listview, titanium-mobile

I am developing mobile app on alloy(1.2.2) on android:
settings.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="settings">    
        <ListItem id="settingsListView">
            <ListSection id="settingsListSection" headerTitle="My Settings">

            </ListSection>
        </ListItem>

    </View>

</Alloy>
```

settings.js

```
var settingsListData=[
        {properties:{title:'Profile'}},
        {properties:{title:'Change Password'}},
        {properties:{title:'Edit Clouds'}}
        ];

$.settingsListSection.setItems(settingsListData);

$.settings.open();
```

It gives error- Object has no method 'add' Why is this error coming? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the <ListView> tag available on Alloy 1.2.2?

Answer (score 2):

You trying to open a view which is causing this problem. Since Ti.UI,View component doesn't have open methd. Try to use Ti.UI.Window component instead of Ti.UI,View. i.e. replace the content of your settings.xml file with below one,

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="settings">    
        <ListItem id="settingsListView">
            <ListSection id="settingsListSection" headerTitle="My Settings">

            </ListSection>
        </ListItem>

    </Window>

</Alloy>
```

Comment: It would be even better if put ALLOY tag first; inside ALLOY tag, put WINDOW tag; inside WINDOW tag, put VIEW tag; finally, put LIST ITEM tag.